Wi-Fi not working and Wi-Fi Settings not visible in Settings on Linux
I have Dell Latitude 5480, pre-installed with Windows 10, along which I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.
This combination was working fine for months until I opened Power Statistics and suddenly Wi-Fi stopped working!
Then, I tried almost everything from online forums like Turning off hibernation, unchecking Turn off device to save power, etc. in Windows and also so many things on Ubuntu side but, nothing worked!
Now, I've removed both, and installed Fedora Workstation 40 only in hope that this will fix the issue (this means re-installing the OS) but, still not working.
The Wi-Fi h/w is fine and it is Intel 8265. And Bluetooth Tethering, Ethernet and USB Tethering works fine.
Current State:

OS: Fedora Workstation 40
Wi-Fi: Not working.

lspci -nv -d ::02xx

00:1f.6 0200: 8086:15d7 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: 1028:07a7
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 136
    Memory at ef200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e

nmcli device show

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         E0:80:6B:D8:BC:4B
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:80:6B:D8:BC:4B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         E0:80:6B:D8:BC:4B
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         E0:80:6B:D8:BC:4B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     POCO X5 5G Network
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.44.132/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.44.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.44.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 750
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.44.1, mt = 750
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.44.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2409:40c2:1019:8578:6187:a2e4:d4e6:6ddd/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         fe80::1c3e:ef18:e7f0:2590/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::e280:6bff:fed8:bc4b
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2409:40c2:1019:8578::/64, nh = ::, mt = 750
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::e280:6bff:fed8:bc4b, mt = 750
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2409:40c2:1019:8578::6a

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected (externally))
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     lo
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         A4:4C:C8:2D:0C:07
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

Before sudo modprobe iwlwifi
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
<no o/p>

After sudo modprobe iwlwifi
lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               544768  0
cfg80211             1421312  1 iwlwifi

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD DC P4101/Pro 7600p/760p/E 6100p Series (rev 03)

lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b96 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:5832 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor Smartcard reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

After going through all these steps we spoke in the comments, if the Wi-Fi still doesn't work, it looks like there might be a hardware defect.
Check if the Wi-Fi module is installed and active:
Run the commands lsmod | grep iwlwifi and iwconfig to verify if the Wi-Fi module is loaded.
If the module is not active, try loading it manually with sudo modprobe iwlwifi.
Install alternative firmware or drivers:
If possible, install all relevant firmware or drivers for your Wi-Fi module and test again.
Restart the Network Manager:
After loading the module, restart the Network Manager with sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager and consider rebooting the system.
Check the kernel logs:
Install the wireless-tools package if it's not available, and check the kernel logs with dmesg | grep iwlwifi for any missing firmware.
Check the Wi-Fi switch or FN keys:
Ensure your laptop has a physical Wi-Fi switch or try enabling/disabling it using the FN key combined with one of the F1-F12 keys.
Check power management settings:
In the power management settings, ensure that the Wi-Fi adapter is not set to turn off to save power.
Test with a Live ISO:
Boot from a Live ISO of another operating system (e.g., Ubuntu, Debian) and see if Wi-Fi works there. This can help determine if it's a hardware or software issue.
Check the BIOS and reset the BIOS:
Check the BIOS and reset, to ensure the Wi-Fi module is not disabled.

Tried everything you suggested but, no luck! I'll check the h/w again once I get time and will update here.

Wi-Fi is working now! I removed the battery and NIC for some time then, connected them again and voilà! IDK, if it was h/w connection issue or some internal state reset due removal of battery but, now it is working fine! Thanks.

Since the WiFi adapter does not appear in the lspci listing, it seems to have been completely disconnected from the PCIe bus.
Some laptops have a mechanical switch or function key for "flight mode", that disables WiFi transmitters. This would be one possible cause for the WiFi adapter apparently vanishing completely off the bus like that. Normally, the PCIe-connected WiFi adapter should be detectable by lspci even without drivers, but a "flight mode" switch/function implemented in a suitable way can disable it completely.
In Dell Latitude 5480 Owner's Manual, page 16 says the keystroke to enable/disable wireless would be Fn+PrntScr. However, that doesn't seem plausible, as according to the picture of the keyboard on page 14, PrntScr itself is a Fn key combination, and the symbols on the keyboard would suggest it could be Fn+Home instead.
Depending on the current state of the "Fn key lock", pressing the appropriate key either alone, or together with the Fn key might allow the WiFi adapter to reappear. Normally it should be then detected by the kernel, which should trigger the appropriate module to be autoloaded if it isn't alreadly loaded.
If this does not help, also check the BIOS settings, paying particular attention to the "Wireless Radio Control" setting in the "Power Management" BIOS settings screen, and all the options in the "Wireless" BIOS settings screen. (Pages 80 and 82 in the Owner's Manual linked above.)
Based on your later comments, and the fact that even Ubuntu 24.04 LTS cannot detect the wireless adapter any more, it looks like either the WiFi adapter itself or the "flight mode" circuitry of the laptop is broken.

I tried toggling the Flight mode through button on keyboard as well as through UI but, Wi-Fi is not appearing. Also, Wireless Radio Control is at default state as shown in manual

I've also tried resetting the BIOS settings to defaults but, no change!
